# How to create a trigger?

Tags: sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create Trigger in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358975/create-trigger-in-sql-server)

I'm trying to create a trigger that says a customer cannot rent more than 2 vehicles from my tables below.  Some help please?

```
CREATE TABLE Customer
(   
    Cust_ID numeric primary key , 
    Cust_fname varchar(20),
    Cust_lname varchar(20),
    sex varchar(15),
    Cust_street varchar(30),
    Cust_parish varchar(30),
    Cust_cc# numeric(30),
    Cust_trn# numeric (20),
);

CREATE TABLE Vehicle
(
    cust_ID numeric ,
    V_ID numeric primary key not null , 
    Body_type varchar(20),
    License# varchar(20),
    V_year varchar(15),
    chassis# numeric(30),
    unladen_weight varchar(30),
     make varchar(30),
    Color varchar (20),
    Eng# varchar(20),
    fuel_type varchar(30),
    V_weight numeric (30),
    Foreign key (Cust_ID)references Customer,
);

create table Car 
(
   V_ID numeric not null,
   Foreign key (V_ID)references Vehicle,
);

create table truck
( 
    V_ID numeric not null,
    truck_length varchar(30) ,
    max_clearance numeric,
    laden_weight numeric,
    haul_cap  numeric,
    Foreign key (V_ID)references Vehicle,
);

Create table rents 
(
     Cust_ID numeric ,
     V_ID numeric not null,
     desposit numeric,
     date_of_rent date ,
     validID varchar (10),
     proof_of_add varchar (10),
     Foreign key (Cust_ID)references Customer,
     foreign key (V_ID) references vehicle,
);
```

Comment: What's your question? I just see a lot of Create table but nothing related with the trigger itself.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.This isn't a "please write my code for me site". You need to post what you've tried that isn't working and explain why it's not working as you'd expect or what errors you're receiving. Also, you need to edit the tags to indicate what database you're using, as they vary in syntax. Please keep in mind that we have no information to go by except what's in your question - we can't read your screen (or your mind) from here.

Answer (score 0):

The couple `cust_ID` and `V_ID` must be unique ?

Create an unique index in table rents on those fields.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing is that different DBs have different trigger procedures etc.

However, here is an example for Postgres.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_insert_trigger()
  RETURNS "trigger" AS
$BODY$
declare
    cnt integer;
begin
    select count(*) into cnt from test where id = NEW.id;
    if (cnt >= 2) then
        raise exception 'Can not insert more than 2 of same thing.';
    end if;
end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
ALTER FUNCTION test_insert_trigger()
  OWNER TO postgres;


CREATE TRIGGER test_insert_trigger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON test
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE test_insert_trigger();
```

All it does is check if more than 2 of the row you're about to insert or update exist in the DB. Change the query criteria to suit your app.

But the essence is there.