# Insert a row into table A whenever a row is inserted into table B

Tags: sql, procedure

i have one table called "**student**" in which **student_id** is primary key.
i want to create new table called "**new_stud**".
when new student record is inserted into "**student**" table, newly created **student_id** is automatically inserted into "**new_stud**" table.

i want this solution by "merge" two tables,but without using cursor.

Comment: First, you should tag your question with the database you are using.  Second, if you want an "automatic insertion", you shouldn't be thinking "cursor", you should be thinking "trigger".

Comment: ***Which RDBMS*** is this for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when new student record is inserted into "student" table, newly created student_id is automatically inserted into "new_stud" table.

You need a **trigger**.

You did not specify which database you are using. The following two links are for SQL Server, but the concept is the same in most relational databases:

- [Create Trigger in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3358975/87698) (StackOverflow)
- [CREATE TRIGGER (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) (MSDN)

Basically, you create an `INSERT` trigger that inserts a new entry into `new_stud` whenever an insert is made into `student`. In SQL Server, the syntax would be as follows:

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_student_trigger ON student
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO new_stud (student_id)
   SELECT student_id FROM inserted;
END
```

Comment: how can i do with MERGE query .because execution of trigger can slow down the process just little bit. @Heinzi

Comment: @TanvirPatel: That's like asking "how can I do with a butterfly". A MERGE query is not required here.