# Is it possible to obtain a notification from MySQL for a running a program?

Tags: php, python, mysql, notifications, udf

I'd like to know if it's possible to have, for example, a python program waiting for input and as a database change occurs in a specific table it would notify the python program with the information I want to obtain from that exact table.

Thanks in advance.

PS: I know of the existence of sys_exec, but i'd like to know if it's possible in another way other than using UDF's.

Comment: You can use a trigger: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3358975/create-trigger-in-sql-server

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i'm also aware of this of course @neuronet, the only thing example I see however, is that the notification is sent by e-mail, i want to send it like an argument for example so that it can either be used directly by another component I shall create later and external to the database, probably in python, to either access the database with that info or just do stuff.
In short, as I might not have explained myself well is, I want to know if there's a command that executes a piece of code or notifies a python program, for example, that I can use in a trigger.

Comment: @Selcuk since you both called out the triggers I commented on that, every help is welcome

Comment: @devilzzord I would strongly recommend writing up a SSCCE, a **minimal** example that shows a) exactly what you wish it would do, and b) what you have tried (and, if relevant, why it doesn't work). Include this in an edited version of your question. Such specifics will make it *much* more likely for you to get a rapid answer from the experts here (they can just tweak your SSCCE). I don't know the answer, it's outside my wheelhouse (I'd look into setting up a client-server system). Also, I'd mention triggers in an updated question, rather than leaving it here to languish in the comments.